# app engine datastore stats on development server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get a list of entity types that have been persisted as [documented](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats.html), but the queries [do not return any results on the development server](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4125).

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
PreparedQuery kindStats = datastore.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Kind__"));

for (Entity kindStat : kindStats.asList(withDefaults())) {
  String kind_name = (String) kindStat.getProperty("kind_name");
}
```

Nor does this work on the development server:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity globalStat = datastore.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Total__")).asSingleEntity();
Long totalBytes = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("bytes");
Long totalEntities = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("count");
```

Is there another way to do this, or is it not supposed to be possible?

Comment: @Nick Johnson any input?

Comment: I believe Riley is correct - stats, at least in the Java SDK, don't work in the dev server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't find the documentation to support this belief, but I believe that:

- stats don't work on the development server right now
- Google is planning on making them work before too long

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/eb07eb384e0275a8/1770f5246c4d6dd7?lnk=gst&q=statistics+dev+server#1770f5246c4d6dd7

Comment: I'm sad to accept this answer. I hope one day it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This url below can help you:

[PreparedQuery.countEntities() clarifications](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/f97bdd5bdf91c114?pli=1)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.